# What certification is required

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am busy setting up our first Sitecore team. We have our first developer, but he never finished his official Sitecore certification.

I know that we can't let him work on our Sitecore license without certification.

So I thought I will check with community that what minimum level of certification is required to work on Sitecore (to ensure that our Sitecore support is not void).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gaurav,
If your developer has experience working  in Sitecore and you are confident about his/her previous experience  then I believe there is no harm in allowing him to work on Sitecore license . 
However I caution you to keep your sitecore license encrypted so that it can't be used on a personal machine.

Doing a sitecore certification has a lot of advantages such as
It gives you credibility in the sitecore community and market.
You can contact the sitecore support team with your Sitecore certification email id attached to your client Sitecore licenses.

So I will suggest you to ask him to appear for sitecore Developer certification which cost only 300$. Below is the link for Study Aids:

https://sitecore.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000067853-sitecore-certified-platform-associate-developer-exam-study-guide-

Comment: Thanks @Krishna. I will definitely consider the site core developer certification.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, If you are satisfied with my comments , please mark this as answer :)

Answer (score 6):

There is some information that you are missing, like, are you trying to setup as a Sitecore Partner or are you a Sitecore client?

But here are some points:

- You do not need to be Sitecore certified to work on a Sitecore build, that would include using your Sitecore license locally to build the site. There is no requirement for certification to work on a Sitecore site that I know of. It will **not** invalidate your support agreement with Sitecore
- However, if you are trying to be a Sitecore Partner, then there are certain requirements for that around how many certified developers you have. Those requirements can change so it is best to speak to your Sitecore rep about them
- Support and File access is something important to think about tho, if you are not certified, you will not have access to the Sitecore support portal, or access to download installation files/modules from https://dev.sitecore.net/, this can make things tricky when trying to implement a Sitecore site.

As for the level of certification, the only requirement for support and file access is the basic certification. It is up to you if you feel like your developers would benefit from the higher level one.

Comment: I think they still need dev licenses, if they are a client and not an implementation partner. I think we are both unclesr if they are a dev shop or a client.

Answer (score 1):

Cliff notes:

- You only need to have developer licenses for your in house developers. Your Sitecore partners will already have their own partner licenses for their devs.
- No one can contact Sitecore support without out a certification and a Sitecore portal login.